# Compatibility of module structures via restriction of scalars and annihilators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $M$ be an $A$-module. Let $I$ be an ideal contained in the annihilator of $M$. Then, we know that $M$ is a left $A/I$-module and that $M$ is in fact a $(A, A/I)$-multimodule in the sense of Algebra $I$ by Bourbaki.

Does the $A$-module structure on $M$ coincide with the $A$-module structure on $\pi_*(M)$ corresponding to the canonical ring projection $\pi: A\to A/I$. I recall that $\pi_*(M)$ is the underlying additive group $M$ equipped with the scalar multiplication $a\cdot m:=\pi(a)\cdot m$.

Comment: The fact that $I$ is contained in the annihilator implies that for any $a \in A$, $i \in I$, and $m \in M$ one has $(a + i) \cdot m = a \cdot m + i \cdot m = a \cdot m$. Thus $\pi(a) \cdot m = (a + I) \cdot m$ is well defined as $a \cdot m$.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I thought, as well. So, the identity map $m\mapsto m$ is an $A$-linear isomorphism from $\pi_*(M)$ to $M$, is it?

Comment: Yes, this is the case indeed.

Comment: Thank you. The claim that $M$ is a left $(A, A/I)$-multimodule makes sense, right?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense to me.

Comment: I should be more precise. When I say left $(A, A/I)$-multimodule, I do not simply mean that $M$ has a left $A$-module and a left $A/I$-module structure but that these structures are also compatible with one another as explained in Algebra $I$ by Bourbaki. So, it makes sense to you in this sense?

Comment: I think so, as the two actions commute.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for these comments.